# WP7 Bing Maps Pushpin template with image doesn't show up

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

My ultimate goal is to have pushpins with custom images on a Bing Map in a WP7 app. I have created a control template and a map with a pushpin. Right now, I can get the default pushpins to show up, but nothing shows when I try to template it. Here's what I have right now:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Image Source="/Images/Pins/pin.png" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<my:Map Name="mapMain" CredentialsProvider="CredKey">
    <my:Pushpin/>
</my:Map>
```

If I apply the PushpinControl template nothing shows up:

```
<my:Pushpin Template="{StaticResource BoaPushpinControlTemplate}" />
```

If I remove the template, it shows the default black shape.

I must be doing my template incorrectly, but I don't know what the problem is. Can I not have an image in the ControlTemplate?

Comment: Call me Mr Silly but just for the sake of argument try specifying literal coordinates and see whether anything shows up there. I've had some odd behaviour with pins not working unless they were initialised with literals (I set the location in code in response to user action).

Answer (score 1):

If you arent using ItemSource binding on the Map then use simple content control approach

```
   <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}">
            <Image Source="/Images/Pins/pin.png"   />
   </maps:Pushpin>
```

Or if you dynamically populating the push-pins use the below approach

```
 <maps:Map x:Name="map" >
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Pins/pin.png"   />
                </maps:Pushpin>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:Map>
```

Comment: Good thinking, but it wasn't the problem. I added height and width and it's still not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this thread is a little bit old I'm going to post my suggestion:

Try out this link [Working with Pushpins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588383%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), it is working for me (create a new style and use it in pushpin declaration)

(App.xaml, **do not forget the namespace!**)

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" >

<Application.Resources>    
    <Style TargetType="m:Pushpin" x:Key="PushpinStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="m:Pushpin">
                    <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="path_to_pic" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

(in the xaml there the map is)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <m:Map x:Name="Map" Mode="Aerial"
              CredentialsProvider="CredKey">
        <m:MapItemsControl x:Name="Content">
            <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
```

If this isn't working check if the Build Action of your picture is set to content.

Took me a while to figure this out, so i hope i could help someone, despite the fact that this thread is old. ;)